# Obtaining the least means squares from MixedLM model

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, statsmodels

I'm not the best statistician by a long shot, but I was trying to obtain the **least squares means** of my fit after fitting a mixed linear effect model using `statsmodels.api.MixedLM`.

By printing the summary of the fit, I only see that it returns the following table:

```
                  Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
==========================================================================
Model:                    MixedLM       Dependent Variable:       Tau     
No. Observations:         155           Method:                   ML      
No. Groups:               20            Scale:                    0.0015  
Min. group size:          3             Log-Likelihood:           262.8731
Max. group size:          13            Converged:                Yes     
Mean group size:          7.8                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Coef.  Std.Err.   z    P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
const                            0.147    0.012 11.775 0.000  0.123  0.172
HF_or_Control (0=control, 1=HF) -0.014    0.018 -0.816 0.414 -0.049  0.020
Group Var                        0.001    0.014                           
==========================================================================
```

I see that `R` has the function `lsmeans` which would actually return all the information that I'm looking for, but is there a similar function in Python's `scipy` or `statsmodels` that does something similar?

Comment: I know the post is old but perhaps you can share if you found what can be done in python to get this information? thanks

Comment: Hi @HavingNoHead, nope, I did not find it.